# Counting query optimization in mysql

Tags: mysql, performance

I have total 1629664 records in the `users` table.

If I am using `SELECT count(u.id) FROM users` it is returning a result within `0.00053` seconds, That's good!!!

If I am going to JOIN with `SELECT count(u.id) FROM users u INNER JOIN user_profile p ON p.user_id = u.id and p.is_delete = 0` it is returning a result within 5.67 or more seconds, That's not good for me, How can we optimize this one?

Additionally, if I add more column in `where` with query

```
SELECT  count(u.id)
    FROM  `users` `u`
    INNER JOIN  `user_profile` `p`  ON `p`.`user_id` = `u`.`id`
      and  `p`.`is_delete` = 0
    WHERE  `u`.`gender` in (1,0)
      AND  `u`.`status` = 1
      AND  `u`.`is_delete` =0
      AND  `u`.`user_role` = 2
      AND  `u`.`id` <> 5720962
      AND  `u`.`search_n_dashboard` = 'visible'
```

it is returning a result within 12.45 or more seconds, I need to optimize this one.

I have used indexing 
`CREATE INDEX users_index ON users (id);
CREATE INDEX user_profile_index ON user_profile (user_id);`

Please suggest me, how can I optimize with more?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

looking tor your on and where condition you could use a composite index

```
  On table  users   ( gender , id , status, is_delete , user_role ,id , search_n_dashboard)
```

and

```
 On table user_profile ( is_delete ,user_id )
```

based on these index  you could try inverting the tables   (changing the lead  table) 
and also avoid the IN clause using  INNER ON subselect

```
SELECT count(u.id) 
FROM `user_profile` `p`
INNER JOIN  `users` `u`  ON `p`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` and `p`.`is_delete` = 0 
INNER JOIN ( select 1  as gender union select 2  ) T on T.gender = u.gender
WHERE `u`.`status` = 1 
      AND `u`.`is_delete` =0 
        AND `u`.`user_role` = 2 
          AND `u`.`id` <> 5720962 
            AND `u`.`search_n_dashboard` = 'visible'
```

and also you could use FORCE the index  for join

```
SELECT count(u.id) 
FROM `user_profile` `p`
INNER JOIN  `users` `u` FORCE INDEX FOR JOIN (`your_index_for_join`)  ON `p`.`user_id` = `u`.`id` and `p`.`is_delete` = 0 
INNER JOIN ( select 1  as gender union select 2  ) T on T.gender = u.gender
WHERE `u`.`status` = 1 
      AND `u`.`is_delete` =0 
        AND `u`.`user_role` = 2 
          AND `u`.`id` <> 5720962 
            AND `u`.`search_n_dashboard` = 'visible'
```

Comment: Should i need to delete previous indexes from above tables?

Comment: you should check in explain plan if the new index  is used  or not  .. if not the you hsould delete the index  probably only the one on user_profile

Comment: Yes, I have checked with both indexes. By using both indexes the result is returning with 13 seconds and more. After removing index of the user_profile table the result is returning 8 seconds. but still, it is not fast. How can we more optimize this one?

Comment: I have posted  another suggestion  .. hope is useful    .. be sure you have also fast disk  and enough memory

Comment: Thank you for the replying us, I will check it and inform you soon for the same.

Comment: It would be great if you can suggest me which configuration will be needed to optimize the MySQL query.

Comment: What  do you mean  .?. in my answer  there are alreday  some soggestion  ..

Comment: Yes, You has said about fast disk and enough memory. 
But it would be great if you will know me about that configuration based on your opinion. cause of your above suggestion is not working to me as well

Comment: For more, like to inform you we have an issue with the big offset. I mean if I try to same then it is fine for me with lowest offset query getting the load in highest offset.

Comment: For more, like to inform you we have an issue with the big offset. I mean if I try to same then it is fine for me with lowest offset query getting the load in highest offset.

Comment: I don't see offset in my query  .. i don't understand?

Comment: @scaisEdge - Put the `=` columns _first_, not _last_ in a composite index.

Comment: @Kamlesh - Get rid of indexes you are not using in _any_ query.  And get rid of any index that is the leftmost part of some other index; eg, get rid of `INDEX(a,b)` if you have `INDEX(a,b,c)`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, `u.id` is unique.  Hence, you can simplify your query to:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM user_profile p 
WHERE p.is_delete = 0;
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `user_profile(is_delete)`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply

But I want to check some condition in users tables as well.

Comment: @Kamlesh . . . Your question was about optimizing the performance of the query you gave.  If you really have another query, then ask *another* question.

Comment: Thank you for the replying us, but it is not a solution for me. I can't do it except users table.

Answer (score 0):

Have these indexes:

```
u:  (status, is_delete, user_role, search_n_dashboard, gender)  -- `gender` last
p:  (user_id, is_delete)  -- in either order
```

Don't say `COUNT(x)` unless you need to check `x` for being `NULL`; simply say `COUNT(*)`.

The 0.00053s is bogus -- you have the Query cache turned on.  Time the queries again thus:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
```

to avoid the QC.

For clarity for the reader, use `ON` to say how the tables are related, not for filtering.  That is move `p.is_delete = 0` to the `WHERE` clause.

Can't `status` and `is_delete` be rolled into a single column?

How many "genders" do you have?  If you have only 2, then get rid of the test; what you have makes it difficult to optimize.

More on writing indexes:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql